# Parse Comma Delimited File without using <string>

Tags: c++

I have a file which looks like:

```
123,Cheese,Butter
78,Milk,Vegetable,Fish
```

and I wish to read each line into a data type `List` which has `int num` and `char things[3][10]` using overloaded operator >>. So far I have:

```
friend istream& operator>> (istream &is, List &rhs)
{
  char comma;
  is >> rhs.num >> comma >> ... (I don't know how to continue)

  return is;
} // operator>>
```

Am I doing it right using `char comma` to skip a comma? How do I read different entries with different lengths separated by comma without using string?

Comment: use [istream::getline()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/) and parse the line yourself.

Comment: The comma is a problem when a locale (in use) uses ',' as a decimal point and the rest is not delimited by white spaces, hence it is a single string. Yes (@NathanOliver) getline is a good first bet.

Comment: Switch over to std::string.  Like `std::string things[3];`.  You can do cool things like `std::getline(is, item, ',');` which will read letters into the string `item` until a comma is read.

Comment: You should also check out the similar questions to yours (not *exact* duplicates): [Read CSV file](https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+c%2B%2B+read+csv&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8).  Your format is known as a Comma Separated Values or CSV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be only a pseudocode but if you really need to avoid std::string your best choice is to make it more or less look like this:

```
istream &operator >>(istream &s, YourType &mylist) {
   char mybuf[256];
   s.read(mybuf, 256);
   char *beg = mybuf;
   char *cur = beg;
   while (cur != mybuf + 256 && *cur!=0) {
      if (*cur == '\n') {
         mylist.addnext();
      }
      if (*cur == ',') {
         *cur = 0; //to make the char string end on each comma
         mylist.current.add(beg);
         beg = cur + 1;
      }
   }
}
```

Remember that if `YourType` will be for example `vector<vector<const char *>>` you will need to add the `operator >>` into the std namespace.

Comment: Can the process be simplified with any std::cstring method like strtok?

Comment: If I really need the low level parsing I always use `bison + flex`. The approach is more flexible and operate only on C-style structs... It even allows to use regular expression.

Comment: Of course it also need a little bit more effort so it depends on the situation.